# Capture and return unselectable text

Tags: autohotkey

I'm calling AHK from a Perl script.  How do I to capture unselectable text (like the text in a Command Prompt window, but I don't have something like the Edit=>Mark option in Command Prompt) from a window using AHK and return the value back to the Perl script?

**Update:** I realize I can transfer data between the two scripts reading/writing a temporary file, but I would prefer something different...

I am not sure if Perl code is relevant to my question, but the line that initiates AHK is:

```
 $data = `autohotkey.exe script.ahk data1 data2`;
```

The 'window' is a corporate ERP system that I cannot directly query.  The information in the 'window' is displayed, but not selectable.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What is the exact type of window from which you are trying to retrieve text? How do you open this window in the first place? Could you also provide the relevant Perl code?

Comment: It seems, that you want your AHK script to write to stdout. This can be achieved with [FileAppend](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/FileAppend.htm). Example: `FileAppend,This is a test of stdout,*` Since I don't know much about Perl, I don't know if or how you can capture a process' stdout. Also, some ERP systems offer a functionality to export content to the clipboard. Specifically SAP lets you do that in some cases. If you already analyzed the ERP window with a window spy, I suppose there's not much you can do.

Comment: FileAppend is 1/2 the solution!  For what it is worth, the variable `$data` in my Perl code receives all the stdout. Not SAP and no such luck on exporting the data from the ERP system.  Currently, I have a solution using an [OCR plugin](http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=74227)

Comment: Though you didn't answer my respective question, I suppose you did analyze your ERP window with a window spy unsuccessfully. Communicating the other way around via standard streams should be possible as well. Nonetheless, your question is still very vague; many questions come to mind: 1. If it's not SAP, what is your ERP system's name? 2. What do your Perl and AHK scripts do? 3. What kind of data gets passed around between them? 4. What is the ERP window's role in all of it? It would be advantageous if you elaborated on the overall process/workflow your problem is involved in.

Answer (score 1):

**shaun5**

> How do I to capture unselectable text (like the text in a Command
>   Prompt window, but I don't have something like the Edit=>Mark option
>   in Command Prompt)...

I have a couple examples:

---

Retrieve multiple lines:

```
ptr:=A_PtrSize ? "Ptr":"UInt", suffix:=A_IsUnicode ? "W":"A", numReaded:=data:=""
INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE:=-1, STD_INPUT_HANDLE:=-10, STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE:=-11
VarSetCapacity(buffer, (size:=1030)*(A_IsUnicode ? 2:1))

Run, % "cmd.exe",,, procID
WinWaitActive, % "ahk_pid"procID
;~ Input, dummyVar, % "I", % "{vk20}" ; wait a space button to press
;~ WinGet, procID, PID, A
SendEvent, % "{Raw}TEST WRITE TO CONSOLE"
If !DllCall("AttachConsole", "UInt", procID, A_PtrSize ? "UInt":"")
{
   WinClose, % "ahk_pid"procID
   MsgBox, 262192, % A_LineNumber, % "Fail attach to console", % 2.5
   ExitApp
}
If (hConsole:=DllCall("GetStdHandle", "Int", STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
                                    , A_PtrSize ? "Ptr":""))=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE
{
   DllCall("FreeConsole")
   WinClose, % "ahk_pid"procID
   MsgBox, 262192, % A_LineNumber, % "Fail retrive a handle of console", % 2.5
   ExitApp
}
If !DllCall("ReadConsoleOutputCharacter"suffix, ptr, hConsole
                                              , ptr, &buffer
                                              , "UInt", size
                                              , "UInt", 0 ; begin read from first row
                                              , "UInt*", numReaded
                                              , A_PtrSize ? "UInt":"")
{
   DllCall("FreeConsole")
   WinClose, % "ahk_pid"procID
   MsgBox, 262192, % A_LineNumber, % "Fail get data from console", % 2.5
   ExitApp
}
; line width is 320 pixels (property/layout/screen buffer size),
; here I cut the unnecessary white spaces in each row
Loop, % numReaded
   Mod(A_Index, 320) ? data.=Chr(NumGet(buffer, (A_Index-1)*(A_IsUnicode ? 2:1)
                                              , A_IsUnicode ? "UShort":"UChar"))
                . "" : data:=RTrim(data)"`r"
MsgBox, 262208, % A_LineNumber, % RTrim(data) ;, % 2.5
DllCall("FreeConsole")
WinClose, % "ahk_pid"procID
```

---

Retrieve specified line:

```
ptr:=A_PtrSize ? "Ptr":"UInt", suffix:=A_IsUnicode ? "W":"A", numReaded:=""
INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE:=-1, STD_INPUT_HANDLE:=-10, STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE:=-11
VarSetCapacity(buffer, (size:=319)*(A_IsUnicode ? 2:1))

Run, % "cmd.exe",,, procID
WinWaitActive, % "ahk_pid"procID
;~ Input, dummyVar, % "I", % "{vk20}" ; wait a space button to press
;~ WinGet, procID, PID, A
SendEvent, % "{Raw}TEST WRITE TO CONSOLE"
If !DllCall("AttachConsole", "UInt", procID, A_PtrSize ? "UInt":"")
{
   WinClose, % "ahk_pid"procID
   MsgBox, 262192, % A_LineNumber, % "Fail attach to console", % 2.5
   ExitApp
}
If (hConsole:=DllCall("GetStdHandle", "Int", STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
                                    , A_PtrSize ? "Ptr":""))=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE
{
   DllCall("FreeConsole")
   WinClose, % "ahk_pid"procID
   MsgBox, 262192, % A_LineNumber, % "Fail retrive a handle of console", % 2.5
   ExitApp
}
If !DllCall("ReadConsoleOutputCharacter"suffix, ptr, hConsole
                                              , ptr, &buffer
                                              , "UInt", size
                                              , "UInt", 3<<16 ; skip some rows
                                              , "UInt*", numReaded
                                              , A_PtrSize ? "UInt":"")
{
   DllCall("FreeConsole")
   WinClose, % "ahk_pid"procID
   MsgBox, 262192, % A_LineNumber, % "Fail get data from console", % 2.5
   ExitApp
}
; cut the unnecessary white spaces and show
MsgBox, 262208, % A_LineNumber, % RTrim(StrGet(&buffer, numReaded
                                                      , A_IsUnicode ? "UTF-16":"CP0"))
DllCall("FreeConsole")
WinClose, % "ahk_pid"procID
```